# Just show some Controls

Tags: fabricjs

I have some line objects in fabricjs. When the user selects them I'd like there just to be a small box at the ends of the lines. The default selection shape of a rectangle all the way around the line is not to my liking.

I don't need controls, because the user can't resize the line. But the default controls which appear at the ends of the line would do just fine. Is there any way that I can have only these two controls appear? Or am I best just creating two new fabricjs objects and sticking them at the ends of the line myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>*IF I understood you correctly*</sub>

You could *use* [**`fabric.Object#setControlsVisibility`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html) to disable individual controls and only have those controls you want

and to prevent object *scaling / resizing*, set ...

```
lockScalingX: true
lockScalingY: true
```

---

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    width: 635,
    height: 218,
});

line = new fabric.Line([50, 50, 200, 50], {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    stroke: 'black',
    hasBorders: false,
    hoverCursor: 'default',
    lockScalingX: true, // lock scaling
    lockScalingY: true  // ^^
});

// disable controls (except top-left and bottom-right)
line.setControlsVisibility({
    tr: false,
    bl: false,
    ml: false,
    mt: false,
    mr: false,
    mb: false,
    mtr: false
})

canvas.add(line);
```

```css
body{margin:0;overflow:hidden}canvas{border:1px solid #d3d3d3}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. My line could be diagonal, but I can deal with that as follows:var trbl=(line.x1<line.x2);

// disable controls (except top-left and bottom-right)
line.setControlsVisibility({

    tr: trbl,
    bl: trbl,
    tl: !trbl,
    br: !trbl,
    ml: false,
    mt: false,
    mr: false,
    mb: false,
    mtr: false

})

Comment: @RobertU Great !! BTW, be sure to accept the answer if that helped :)

Comment: Actually trbl should be   var trbl=(line.x1<line.x2) ? (line.y2<=line.y1) : (line.y1<line.y2) ;